VS code not completing EXPRESS =>res.sendFile
In VS Code, when I type "res.s" in my index.js file, VS Code does not suggest res.sendFile but only res.send.
I do not understand as I have the ESLint and javascript ES6 plugins installed.
Any idea what could be the issue as everything that belongs to EXPRESS seems not completing in VSCode ?
thx
Checked settings > Javascript suggest = enabled

provide the code fragment or the full code file

Depending on how you write your code the language server may not know the type of res. When not using typescript I often use jsdoc to give type hints to vscode.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
